# How to create thousands or millions of tables at a time in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Could you please advise me SQL-based or database PostgreSQL specific command(s) or flow to create thousands or even millions of similar (same) 2-column-based empty tables in PostgreSQL RDBMS? Maybe based on basic empty table as token 'fw'? 'fw_'+(increment)
The solution has to be as fast as possible. Maybe some trick(?) Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That sounds like a really bad database design.

Comment: What does it have to do with Java?

Comment: Its nessesary for billions of data-in generation

Comment: I am asking for solution "HOW" not "WHY". Apologise for strict neccesity

Comment: "millions of tables" is completely unrealistic for any testing environment. Even "thousands" seems far fetched. If you told us what the what the **real**, underlying problem is you are trying to solve, you might get a better solution to your problem.

Comment: I bet for it). Will see will it go

Comment: Topic raise again. Maybe other RDBMS faster creates? Though this one has benefit in storage for arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL in a loop.

```
do
$$
declare
  l_counter integer;
  l_name text;
  l_sql text;
begin
  for l_counter in 1..10000 loop
    l_name := 'fw_'||to_char(l_counter, 'FM00000000');
    l_sql := format('create table %I (col1 integer, col2 integer)', l_name);
    execute l_sql;
  end loop;  
end;
$$;
```

---

But this sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: Is it extremly quick? Since It crucial to me. The fastest as you know

Comment: @GenEva: that's as fast as it gets.

Comment: Testing... pretty slow for 10000. It's an empty table... Similar tables... as copy of each other. Simpliest as can be with two columns. 10000 similar csv-files with same header in OS have been created much faster on HDD, haven't they?

Comment: Should I auto-edit/auto-copy/manually tablespace some specific files/folders for once created sample to really boost it? Your code is nice, but very slow need x100 faster at least than this solution

Answer (score 0):

Creating 10000 tables or orders on magnitude more is not going to be blindingly fast - it's just not going to happen. But the following MAY be a little quicker.

```
do $$
declare stmt record;
begin 
    for stmt in 
        with s as (select (generate_series (1,100)) n )
        select 'create table tbl_' || to_char(n, 'FM00000000') || ' (i1 integer, i2 integer); ' as t from s
    loop 
        execute stmt.t ;
    end loop; 
end ; $$;
```

As suggested let us know what issue your trying to resolve. Perhaps then someone will see a variable alternation. I would ask: After you create these tables how will you use them and how will you know which one to use?

Comment: Can you please explain, why does operation of creation table take so much time? 10000 similar csv-files with same header in OS have been created much faster on HDD, haven't they? I am trying to use table(s) as containers for multiple generated data, data is simple int[] arrays but has some key wrapped above them (I prefer to use as table-name as a key)

Comment: I seriously doubt 10000vsimilar csv-files

Comment: Sorry, wrong key.  I seriously doubt 10000 (or more) similar csv-files have been created much less much faster, I've never even heard of it. Databases (one purpose) were created to avoid such nonsense. But your statement that you perfer to us "table name" as key indicates you can do just that: Create 1 table, then use whatever name you would have generated ans the PK. Post some representative data then maybe we can suggest an alternative. BTW you complain creating the tables is slow but I can virtually assure you that will be the fastest part of this process.